# How to reliably reference WindowsDesktop.App.Ref at build time

Tags: .net, c++-cli, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

My build (in VS2022) has a C++/CLI assembly that needs to reliably reference types the `WindowsDesktop.App.Ref` package for .NET 6.  Like types in the `WindowsBase` assembly.  I cannot find a way to do this that works for all developers.

I was trying to use the version found in this folder:

```
c:/program files/dotnet/packs/windowsdesktop.app.ref
```

On my brand new machine it looks like this:

[image]

But the problem is that different developers have different "latest" version subfolders here   One developer has only a subfolder named "6.0.8".  Another has "6.0.7".  It seems that updating to the latest Visual Studio would install it, but some of us cannot do that right now for unrelated reasons.

So is there some downloadable MS installer I can run, separate from visual studio that can ensure that one specific version like 6.0.11 lives in that folder?

(Then, i could just ask every developer to install it and hard code the .VCXPROJ file)

OR

Is there some *other* basic .NET 6 base folder that I should be trying to use to get at these types at build time?  Like, say maybe this one?

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App
```

Because here I see that:

[image]

The rules about this stuff confuse me.

Comment: Maybe you can try using [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) but not sure it is applicable to C++/CLI projects.

Comment: The documented way is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli#port-a-ccli-project), "WPF and Windows Forms usage" section.  What it doesn't tell you is that the added FrameworkReference needs to be inside an ItemGroup, that took me an hour.

Comment: @HansPassant Perfect!  Thank you!.  By the way, isn't framework reference a really new thing that they just added to C++/CLI?  I seem to recall reading something about that in the release notes recently...

Comment: Or was that a NuGet thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install either the full SDK with needed version from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) (or install via [Powershell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&tabs=net70#install-with-powershell-automation), see [reference for options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script#options)).

**UPD**

As mentioned in comments, you can add `FrameworkReference` element to the .vcxproj file (see [WPF and Windows Forms usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli#wpf-and-windows-forms-usage) docs) to allow .NET Core C++/CLI projects usage of Windows Forms and WPF APIs:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Unfortunately installing the .NET DesktopRuntime does not affect that `c:/program files/dotnet/packs folder`.  It only affects the second one I listed, `c:/program files/dotnet/shared`.  I can do that if I must.   But the nice thing about using the `dotnet/packs` folder is that in Visual Studio I have a macro that always reliably points me there.  I don't have such a macro for `dotnet/shared`

Comment: @Joe have you tried installing SDK or does it have the same effect in terms of `dotnet/packs` folder?

Comment: Oh I get it now.  The entire SDK, NOT just the DesktopRuntime.! My mistake. Yes, it does look like that will do it.   I was looking at the wrong installer. I can't try it on my work machine for a couple of days but I'm very confident that will work and I will come back here and mark that as the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @Joe hope it helps! If not - I'm out of ideas and we will need to wait for someone smarter)

Comment: Turns out Hans Passant's comment to my original message above did the trick!

Comment: @Joe yep, was wondering if `FrameworkReference` approach which is used to reference workloads [in libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) would work here also.

Comment: @Joe since Hans has not added as answer - updated mine.